# Need a GUI app for group policy login script

Tags: windows, group-policy

I wrote a C# 4.0 application that works on a Windows computer but when using Group Policy to set it as a login script, it does not run.  The application is being called from the same location and using rsop.msc shows that the application should be run.

I see that using C# 4.0 may be a little overkill for this purpose, but it just seems wrong to write a VB6 application to do the same thing.

The requirements for the application states that there need to be specific GUI elements that can't be just text on the window.  I need larger fonts and color elements.

Is there something more appropriate (and current) that I should be using?

Comment: Would you be better off assigning the app through GP, or do you only want it to run at logon?

Comment: It is a logon script defined in GP already.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use powershell? In a lot of cases Powershell can run your C# code too.

Answer (score 0):

group policy supports only  Any language supported by Windows Script Host, including the VBScript, JavaScript, PERL, and MS-DOS®-style batch files (.bat and .cmd).

http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc776182(v=ws.10).aspx